# XPath always returns an empty list

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler

Well, I don't know why the 'title_List' always return none.
I just have tried to change the "User-Agent" but the result is the same.

Can  anybody tell me  where is wrong with my code?

And the Xpath is right by using chrome xpath-helper like following img.

[image]

This is my code:

```
#coding=utf-8
import re
import urllib2
import urllib
from lxml import etree


def init():

    url = 'https://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%E7%BE%8E%E5%A5%B3&ie=utf-8&pn=0'
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50"}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    print(1)
    print(response)
    #shape response get data
    get_title(response)
    print(4)



#get title href
def get_title(response):
    #html->xpath
    html_dom = etree.HTML(response)

    ts = html_dom.xpath('//div[@class="threadlist_lz clearfix"]/div/a[@class="j_th_tit"]/@href')
    print(2)
    print(ts)
    for href in ts:
        full_link='https://tieba.baidu.com'+str(href)
        print(3)
        print(full_link)
```

**Result:（i have deleted some codes because the limitation!）**

```
    1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--STATUS OK-->
    <html>
    ...
<div class="threadlist_lz clearfix">
                <div class="threadlist_title pull_left j_th_tit 
">
    <i class="icon-member-top" alt="会员置顶" title="会员置顶" ></i><i class="icon-good" alt="精品" title="精品" ></i>

    <a rel="noreferrer" href="/p/5006374769" title="【答疑解惑】误删误封绿色通道" target="_blank" class="j_th_tit ">【答疑解惑】误删误封绿色通道</a>
</div><div class="threadlist_author pull_right">

...




2
[]
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @class attribute of your XPath expression is wrong. Change it to `j_th_tit` (with a trailing space) and it will match.

```
//div[@class="threadlist_lz clearfix"]/div/a[@class="j_th_tit "]/@href
```

To avoid these errors, it's often better to use the `contains(...)` function like

```
//div[contains(@class,"threadlist_lz") and contains(@class, "clearfix")]/div/a[contains(@class,"j_th_tit")]/@href
```

This approach is less precise, but most of the time sufficient.

Comment: Still none ：-（   but your expression works right in xpath-helper

Comment: I tested the expression with the original file downloaded from tieba.baidu.com and after adjusting the HTML file to conform to XML standards, I got the correct result. So the problem seems to stem from the difference of HTML and XML files.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how do you adjust it and do you know which reason lead to the difference? Thx a lot

Comment: Well ， i find a solution to use <response.replace(r'<!--','"').replace(r'-->','"')> 
brefore <html_dom = etree.HTML(response)> then the list is not empty.

Comment: I added - by hand - missing closing tags, e.g. for the `<meta...>` tags, so that they look like `<meta... />`. The result was _well-formed_ XML. But to solve your problem you better look into LXML if it supports HTML parsing and not only XML parsing and which options you need.